# Javascript string manipulations with regex

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

Hi guys I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me? On my website I have created a blog. In JavaScript I have created a program to format the text. It uses regular expressions to format/transform the text. At the moment it is having some un expected results. if you scroll to the bottom of the post that is at [this link](http://www.griffithswebdesign.com/Blog/Post/20)  you will see some random tags. I don't know where they have come from or why they are appearing. If anyone could help I would be very appreciative.

this is the javascript used to format the text:

```
function viewPost(val1) {


var msg = val1.innerHTML;
console.log(msg);

    // disable < and > to prevent scripting attacks       
    msg = msg.replace(/<(.*?)>/gi, "&lt;$1&gt;");
    msg = msg.replace(/<\/(.*?)>/gi, "&lt;&#47;$1&gt;");

    // preserve new lines
    msg = msg.replace(/\n/gi, "<br />");

    //colon
    msg = msg.replace(/\:/gi, "&#58;");

    // Basic BBCodes.

    // head large
    msg = msg.replace(/\[hdlg\]/gi, '<h1>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/hdlg\]/gi, '</h1>');
    // head medium
    msg = msg.replace(/\[hdmd\]/gi, '<h2>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/hdmd\]/gi, '</h2>');
    // head small
    msg = msg.replace(/\[hdsm\]/gi, '<h3>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/hdsm\]/gi, '</h3>');
    // bold text
    msg = msg.replace(/\[b\]/gi, "<strong>");
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/b\]/gi, "</strong>");
    // italic text
    msg = msg.replace(/\[i\]/gi, "<em>");
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/i\]/gi, "</em>");
    // underlined text
    msg = msg.replace(/\[u\]/gi, "<u>");
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/u\]/gi, "</u>");
    // centre text
    msg = msg.replace(/\[c\]/gi, '<p style="text-align:center;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/c\]/gi, "</p>");
    // left align text
    msg = msg.replace(/\[l\]/gi, '<p style="text-align:left;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/l\]/gi, "</p>");
    // right align text
    msg = msg.replace(/\[r\]/gi, '<p style="text-align:right;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/r\]/gi, "</p>");
    // justify text
    msg = msg.replace(/\[j\]/gi, '<p style="text-align:justify;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/j\]/gi, "</p>");
    // code blocks
    msg = msg.replace(/\[code\]/gi, '<div style="background:#484848;color:#ffffff;text-align:left;border-radius:8px;padding:10px;overflow:hidden;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/code\]/gi, '</div>');
    // def lists
    msg = msg.replace(/\[def\]/gi, '<dl>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/def\]/gi, '</dl>');
    // def term
    msg = msg.replace(/\[term\]/gi, '<dt>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/term\]/gi, '</dt>');
    // def description
    msg = msg.replace(/\[desc\]/gi, '<dd>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/desc\]/gi, '</dd>');
    // unordered list
    msg = msg.replace(/\[unord\]/gi, '<ul>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/unord\]/gi, '</ul>');
    // ordered list
    msg = msg.replace(/\[ord\]/gi, '<ol>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/ord\]/gi, '</ol>');
    // list item
    msg = msg.replace(/\[item\]/gi, '<li>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/item\]/gi, '</li>');
    // links
    msg = msg.replace(/\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)/gi, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$2');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/url\]/gi, '</a>');
    // images 
    msg = msg.replace(/\[postpic=(.*?)\sclass=(.*?)\stitle=(.*?)\salt=(.*?)\sstyle=(.*?)\]/gi, '<img src="/images/postAssets/$1" class="$2" title="$3" alt="$4" style="$5" />');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/postpic\]/gi, "");
    // font colour [colour=COL] [/colour]
    msg = msg.replace(/\[colour=(.*?)\]/gi, '<span style="color:$1;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/colour\]/gi, '</span>');
    // tables
    msg = msg.replace(/\[table\]/gi, '<table style="padding: 5px;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/table\]/gi, '</table>');
    // table row
    msg = msg.replace(/\[trow\]/gi, '<tr style="border:1px solid #000000;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/trow\]/gi, '</tr>');
    // table header
    msg = msg.replace(/\[thead\]/gi, '<th style="padding: 5px;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/thead\]/gi, '</th>');
    // table data
    msg = msg.replace(/\[tdata\]/gi, '<td style="padding: 5px;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/tdata\]/gi, '</td>');
    // subscript
    msg = msg.replace(/\[sub\]/gi, '<sub>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/sub\]/gi, '</sub>');
    // superscript
    msg = msg.replace(/\[sup\]/gi, '<sup>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/sup\]/gi, '</sup>');



    val1.innerHTML = msg;

    console.log(val1.innerHTML);}
```

Any suggestions you can offer will be gratefully received. As I said I am unsure why this is happening but I am fairly sure its an issue with my JavaScript. The page it is displayed on is an .aspx page, not sure if that has anything to do with it but thought id say just in case. If any further details are required then please let me know and I shall provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code blocks contain text like:

```
List<string> cols = new List<string>();
```

This looks like two `<string>` tags

and

```
<ul>
<li>Colour
<ul>
```

These need to be escaped as they are likely currently getting auto closed by the browser in your `val1.innerHTML = msg;` call.

Comment: Something like  msg = msg.replace(/<string>/gi, "&lt;string&gt;"); ?

Comment: No the HTML in the page should not be HTML - it should be text - you need to escape the entire output in ASP.NET

Comment: Any suggestions as to how? sorry to be a pain, js and regex are not my strong point which I'm working on :)

Comment: You want to be doing this on the server side consider using `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode`.

Comment: You might also want to consider doing all of your regular expression replaces / text formatting on the server side as well.